# Scrollable screen on soft keyboard open, using Constraint layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

How do we make the screen scrollable when the soft keyboard opens up, while using Constraint layout. It can be achieved with flag 'adjustResize' in manifest, while using Linear layout inside Scrollview. But the behaviour is different while using Constraint layout inside Scrollview.
How do we  achieve the required behaviour while using Constraint layout?

The following images show my screen when the soft Keyboard is not open, and when the keyboard is open.

This is my screen when the soft keyboard is NOT open 
[image: This is my screen when the soft keyboard is NOT open]

This is my screen when the soft keyboard is open 
[image: This is my screen when the soft keyboard is open]

I have been looking for a solution to this since days, but I'm not able to find.
Please help!

EDIT:

I have currently modelled my XML as:

```
 <Constraint layout>
             <NestedScrollView>
                         <Constraint layout>
                         </Constraint layout>
            </NestedScrollView>
    
            <Constraint layout>
            </Constraint layout>
    
</Constraint layout>
```

It's not working.

EDIT 2:

My actual XML is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clProgressSignUp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SignupActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_148sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_voodlee"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name as on Pan Card"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.135"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name as on Pan Card"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_thin_line_bright_green"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/bright_green"
                android:textColorHint="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.091"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_thin_line_bright_green"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/bright_green"
                android:textColorHint="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.43"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvErrorMsgEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="* Please enter valid email address"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textColor="@color/voodlee_red"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".1375"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.47"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile Number"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.115"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/bright_green"
                android:textColorHint="@color/fade_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_thin_line_bright_green"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvErrorMsgMobile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="* Please enter valid mobile number"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textColor="@color/voodlee_red"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".135"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5875"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

                />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbTnc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/bright_green"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAgree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I agree to the"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/bright_green"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTnc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="terms and conditions"
                android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14dp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tvAgree"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextSignUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_36sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_proceed_enabled"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:text="Proceed"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:onClick="onClickNext"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semi_bold"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.825"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAlreadyHave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
        android:text="Already have an account?"
        app:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clProgressSignUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing `android: fillViewPort = "true"` attribute from NestedScrollview, and adding an empty view at the end of layout like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clProgressSignUp"
    />
```

This made the screen scrollable, and fulfilled the requirement after using the layout as above and using the flag  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`  in manifest for the Activity.

Comment: HI! I have the same problem as you... what's your working final solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to model your .xml file like this

1. Root layout: ConstraintLayout
2. Child: ScrollView / NestedScrollView
3. NestedScrollView Child: ConstraintLayout
4. Bottom layout: LinearLayout(can be RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout)

Comment: Can the child of root layout be any of Scrollview and NestedScrollView?

Comment: Also, is the 'Bottom layout' mandatory when I can accommodate my views in the Constraint layout that is the direct child of Scrollview?

Comment: I have modelled  my XML as:

<Constraint layout>
         <NestedScrollView>
                     <Constraint layout>
                      </Constraint layout>
          </NestedScrollView>

           <Constraint layout>
           </Constraint layout>

</Constraint layout>

Comment: Yes it can be NestedScrollView or ScrollView. And it is mandatory to add "Bottom Layout" keeping its height to "Match parent" and width to "Wrap content"

Comment: It would be great if you update your question with .xml file.

Comment: Added the XML in question. Pls check.

Comment: In your inner constraint layout add these following tags android:isScrollContainer="true"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clProgressSignUp"

Comment: Did that, still not working. Now my inner constraint layout looks like:

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clProgressSignUp"
        >